# navigation bar in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I achieve navigation bar like this in [image: navigation bar]polymer I have a home toolbar and navigation bar, navigation bar has mydashboard,user,demo horizontally aligned and when I click on user I should see mydashboard and demo and I can also toggle back, when I toggle back  only the url changes the toolbar and naviagtion bar remains constant can anyone create a fiddle and show?

Comment: Can you post a gif instead?

Comment: it's working i used paper tabs and app toolbar